# How to obtain and modify a pixel value here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, image-manipulation

[Listing 2 of Apple's Q & A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html) shows an example of how to modify pixels in a CGImageRef. The problem is: They're not showing *how* to obtain a pixel and modify it's R G B and A values.

The interesting part is here:

```
 void *data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    if (data != NULL)
    {

        // **** You have a pointer to the image data ****

        // **** Do stuff with the data here ****

    }
```

Now, lets say I want to read Red, Green, Blue and Alpha from pixel at x = 100, y = 50. How do I get access to that pixel and it's R, G, B and A components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to know the bytesPerRow of your bitmap, as well as the data type and color format of the pixels in your bitmap.  bytesPerRow can be different from the width_in_pixels*bytesPerPixel, as there might be padding at the end of each line.  The pixels can be 16-bits or 32-bits, or possibly some other size.  The format of the pixels can be ARGB or BRGA, or some other format.

For 32-bit ARGB data:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)bytes;
long int i = bytesPerRow * y + 4 * x;  // for 32-bit pixels
alpha = p[i  ];    // for ARGB 
red   = p[i+1];
green = p[i+2];
blue  = p[i+3];
```

Note that depending on your view transform, the Y axis might also appear to look upside down, depending on what you expect.

Comment: The transformation matrix affects coordinates for drawing into the context, not the layout of the buffer. The y axis of the buffer might be “upside down” compared to the y axis used earlier to draw into this context, but the y axis of the buffer is constant.

Comment: Can you provide some more examples on how to obtain all these values correctly from a CGImageRef?

Comment: @Mikhalo Ivanokov: You can't get pixel component values directly from a CGImage. You need to draw the image into a bitmap context and then look into the context's buffer. You can make the bitmap context one pixel tall and wide and use translation to draw the correct pixel from the image, which greatly simplifies the buffer-access math.

Comment: @Peter: You can: `CGImageGetDataProvider()`, but it's not particularly well documented and you can't modify the image, since CGImage is immutable.

Comment: @tc.: The problem with that is that you then have to adapt to the raster format of the image, which is a ton of work to do correctly even just to make sure you get the format you expect to get, let alone any hypothetical other or future formats. I need not state the obvious problem with blindly assuming you will get any particular format. When you create a bitmap context, you determine its format; then you can safely handle only that format.

Comment: @Peter: Provided you specify a byte order (on ARM, I oddly get big endia by default even though kCGByteOrderDefault is little). You can also check the pixel format and access values directly if they're of the "expected" format, which will tend to avoid an expensive copy in the vast majority of cases.